# why am I triggering quirks mode in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

I'm working on a page that, when I load into IE8 and view the developers tools it tells me that page default is quirks mode.

I've got a strict DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

I even went ahead and put in the explicit standards switch, though I didn't think I'd need to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I can't understand why page default isn't IE8 standards?

Only thing I can think of is that to get to this page, I first have to log in to an application and the first pages I must traverse are old quirks mode pages.  Does IE decide on which mode to use at a server level, or is it supposed to decide page by page?

Thanks!

Comment: you try closing out all your IE8 windows and loading again?

Comment: this solved my quirks mode problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294301/dreamweaver-causing-quirks-mode-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Does IE decide on which mode to use at a server level

Not generally, no. There is the ugliness of the [compatibility view list](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/02/16/just-the-facts-recap-of-compatibility-view.aspx), which is site-specific, but that only kicks you back to IE7-style-Standards Mode, not IE5.5-style-Quirks-Mode.

Your code otherwise looks OK, as long as that DOCTYPE is the very first thing on the page. IE will be forced to `document.compatMode= 'BackCompat'` if there is a comment, PI, XML declaration (prior to IE8) or any non-whitespace textual content before the doctype. If a control character has snuck in that you can't see in your text editor, that could do it.

Example problem page?

Comment: You got it!  Issue was that doctype declaration was not absolutely first thing on page.

Thanks!

Comment: in my case i have some session and some header redirect but if you echo the code after that it will work: `echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';` . you can use any other `doctype`