# Why does IE9 load my site in quirks mode automatically? How can I force it into IE9 standards?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, standards, mode, forwarding, quirks-mode

When I load this page from is regular path or URL everything works just as it should in IE9, but when using the forwarded URL to access it IE9 loads it in quirks mode which removes the entire header from the page leaving only the iframe. If I switch the documents mode to IE9 standards, the header appears but then everything else becomes out of format and messed up. Can anyone help with this?

Normal path (Works perfectly on IE9): http://payrollservers.us/SharedDocs/cbiz/tkg/38330337/index.html

Forwarded URL (Quirks mode in IE9): http://www.cbiztimesolutions2.com

How can I get this page to not load in quirks mode and why is everything our of format when I switch it to ie9 standards manually?

Comment: Your links are the same.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the second link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a http header or meta tag, I would suggest meta tag.

**http Header**

```
name: X-UA-Compatible  
value: IE=edge
```

**Meta Tag** *(put it in the HTML Head Section)*

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

Comment: I am going to add the Meta Tag as you and Dalorzo have recommended.

Comment: Making sure this in in the html was unsuccessful, the forwarded url still loads in quirks mode.

Comment: When I inspect the HTML for both the URLs, they are different. In **Forwarded URL** the meta tag is within a frame *(and not in the parent HTML)*, most probably that is the reason it is not getting applied, try to use the **http Header**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the HTTP Header?

Comment: If you are using IIS Web Server read the detail from http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

Comment: I am sorry but this does not help with my page. I am still unable to find a solutions as to why the site loads in quirks mode from the forward URL.

Comment: Add **<!DOCTYPE html>** as the 1st line in your page, which is not right now in your **Forwarded URL** http://www.cbiztimesolutions2.com. Reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652791/why-am-i-triggering-quirks-mode-in-ie8

Answer (score 0):

Include the edge mode in your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>...</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: I am going to apply your recommendation and upload the changes to see if it works. Thanks, I will keep you updated.

Comment: Even after making sure the edge mode is in the URL, the cbiztimesolutions.com url still loads only in quirks mode which removes the header.

Comment: Yes, I am. Is the site also loading in quirks mode for you in IE9?

Comment: Microsoft does not recommend setting the value for an specific browser but being the case that something is odd. Can you try this?
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
You can read more about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It doesn't look like adding the IE=9 has helped. I have been trying to figure this out for so long.

Comment: This is odd it is actually very well know as solution for what you indicate.